# Replacing a float number in txt file

Tags: python-3.x

Firstly, I would like to say that I am newbie in Python.

I will ll try to explain my problem as best as I can.

The main aim of the code is to be able to read, modify and copy a txt file.

In order to do that I would like to split the problem up in three different steps.

1 -  Copy the first N lines into a new txt file (CopyFile), exactly as they are in the original file (OrigFile)

2 - Access to a specific line where I want to change a float number for other. I want to append this line to CopyFile.

3 - Copy the rest of the OrigFile from line in point 2 to the end of the file.

At the moment I have been able to do step 1 with next code:

```
with open("OrigFile.txt") as myfile:
    head = [next(myfile) for x iin range(10)] #read first 10 lines of txt file

copy = open("CopyFile.txt", "w") #create a txt file named CopyFile.txt

copy.write("".join(head)) #convert list into str

copy.close #close txt file
```

For the second step, my idea is to access directly to the txt line I am interested in and recognize the float number I would like to change. Code:

```
line11 = linecache.getline("OrigFile.txt", 11) #opening and accessing directly to line 11

FltNmb = re.findall("\d+\.\d+", line11) #regular expressions to identify float numbers
```

My problem comes when I need to change FltNmb for a new one, taking into consideration that I need to specify it inside the line11. How could I achieve that?

Comment: You could use a line counter and increment it after writing each line (except line 11) to the new file. If the line counter is at line 11, you can replace the float num and then write it to the file.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer ParvBanks. But I think your idea would work in case just a number is present on line11, is that right?. If you have at the beginning of that line a float number followed by words, would it work? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It will work if there is a number anywhere in line 11 (beginning, end or in the middle). If there are multiple numbers, the regex would match any float number that appears `first` in the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Open both files and write each line sequentially while incrementing line counter.**
**Condition for line 11 to replace the float number. Rest of the lines are written without modifications:**

```
with open("CopyFile.txt", "w") as newfile:
    with open("OrigFile.txt") as myfile:
        linecounter = 1
        for line in myfile:
            if linecounter == 11:
                newline = re.sub("^(\d+\.\d+)", "<new number>", line)
                linecounter += 1
                outfile.write(newline)
            else:
                newfile.write(line)
                linecounter += 1
```

Comment: You'll need a different approach if there are more than one numbers that you want to replace using `re.findall` and a list of numbers that will replace each matching find.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Exactly, that is the question. The structure of line 11 is something like "0.584          bla bla bla". So the point is that I just want to change 0.584 for another float number and mantain the rest of the line as it is. I assume that more job needs to be done in order to do that. My idea was read line 11, identify float number with a variable, assign the new float number to that variable, identify just the final part of line 11 (bla bla bla) and put all together again. Not sure if that is best way or there is other easier.

Comment: Okay, since your line11 starts with the string to be replaced, I have updated my code to match only the number in the beginning of the string.

Comment: Make sure you enter the variable you want to replace in place of `"<new number>"`

Comment: Thank you for your help ParvBanks. The code is working perfectly. Nonetheless, I would like to understand a couple of things. 1º - why are you denying the regular expression as "^(\d+\.\d+)"? And, how do you indicate that you want to copy the rest of line 11? Is by the third argument of re.sub()?

Comment: You can check how this `regex` works in this link: https://regex101.com/r/eHsjZG/1

`^` is to denote start of line and `()` is to capture first matching group.

Comment: You don't need to match the `rest of the line` since you're replacing only the required text in the line keeping everything else same.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help ParvBanks! That link is so useful to understand how regex works!